# The Chaos Game and Benford's law: will I notice the bias?

Tags: probability-distributions, fractals, visualization, chaos-game

> If I construct a Sierpinsky Gasket using [The Chaos Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) algorithm, but the random data I am using to decide the vertex of the next step is ruled by [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law) (so it is partially biased), how would I notice that bias when looking at the Sierpinski Gasket?

[image]
(credit of the image to Wikipedia)

An excerpt from Wikipedia:

> Benford's law, also called the first-digit law, is an observation
>   about the frequency distribution of leading digits in many real-life
>   sets of numerical data. The law states that in many naturally
>   occurring collections of numbers, the leading significant digit is
>   likely to be small. For example, in sets which obey the law, the
>   number $1$ appears as the most significant digit about $30$% of the time,
>   while $9$ appears as the most significant digit less than $5$% of the
>   time.

So if I am deciding the next vertex by taking the first digit of a random number that belongs to a set of numerical data under Bendfor's law, will I notice the bias when looking at the Sierpinsky Gasket?

My intuition is that we would see more points near one of the vertices. For instance if the digit obtained from our "random" set is $1,2,3$ then the next vertex is $V_1$, if $4,5,6$ then $V_2$ and in other case $V_3$. In the example I am writing, there would be more points near $V_1$ due to the bias of Benford's law.

Is this correct? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll notice it!
https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/445696

Source code for posterity:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  speed = 100;

  // Set up the triangle
  radius = min(windowWidth, windowHeight) / 2;
  cx = windowWidth / 2;
  cy = windowHeight / 2;
  v1x = cx + radius * cos(0);
  v1y = cy + radius * sin(0);
  v2x = cx + radius * cos(2 * PI / 3);
  v2y = cy + radius * sin(2 * PI / 3);
  v3x = cx + radius * cos(4 * PI / 3);
  v3y = cy + radius * sin(4 * PI / 3);

  // Probabilities
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law#Mathematical_statement
  p123 = (log(1+1) + log(1+1/2) + log(1+1/3)) / log(10);
  p123456 = p123 + (log(1+1/4) + log(1+1/5) + log(1+1/6)) / log(10);

  // Current point
  px = v1x;
  py = v1y;
}

function draw() {
  for (i = 0; i < speed; ++i) {
    r = random(1);
    if (r < p123) {
      px = (px + v1x) / 2;
      py = (py + v1y) / 2;
    } else if (r < p123456) {
      px = (px + v2x) / 2;
      py = (py + v2y) / 2;
    } else {
      px = (px + v3x) / 2;
      py = (py + v3y) / 2;
    }

    point(px, py);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is $co^{\infty}l$! thank you. Indeed, it seems that not only there are more points near the initially biased vertex, but also in the sub-fractal equivalent vertices as well.

Comment: by the way, your visualization / Maths' videos at Vimeo are very interesting! here are mine if you want to see some complex division visualization https://vimeo.com/user43856725

Comment: That's also quite cool, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisCulter That is a very nice demonstration.  Thank you.